# Having an issue passing button titles to another screen in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

In short I am trying to pass the title of the button from my input screen to my calculator model and once inside the calculator model, a value will be returned based on the button selected. However, currently my calculator is preforming the task WITHOUT waiting for the title of the button. Any ideas on how I can await the button title? I tried future, async, and await functionality but still couldn't get it to work properly.

**Input Screen**

```
class InputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _InputScreenState createState() =>
      _InputScreenState();
}

class _InputScreenState
    extends State<InputScreen> {
  final MyButton selected = MyButton(title3: 'Female', title4: 'Male', title5: 'Unknown');

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    selected.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 250,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: kHeaderGradient,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('images/virus.png'),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  AppBar(
                    leading: null,
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }),
                    ],
                    title: Text(
                      'Gender Multiplier',
                      style: kHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              ValueListenableBuilder<Option>(
                valueListenable: selected,
                builder: (context, option, _) => MakeButtons(
                  num0: 3,
                  num1: 6,
                  makeButtonWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
                  selected: option,
                  onChanged: (newOption) => selected.option = newOption,
                ),
              ),
             
              RoundedButton(
                title: 'Calculate',
                onPressed: () {
                  
                  Calculator calc;
                  calc = Calculator(
                    buttonTitle: selected.title,
                  );

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ResultsScreen(
                        genderMultiplier: calc.calculate(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 80);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 80);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Calculator model**

```
class Calculator {
  Calculator({
    this.buttonTitle,
  });

  String buttonTitle;
  

  double _genderModifier


  String calculate() {
    double getMultiplier() {
      if (buttonTitle == 'Male') {return 2;} 
      else if (buttonTitle == 'Female') {return 1;} 
      else {return 0;}
    }
    if (getMultiplier() == 0) {return 'Does not work';} else {
    _genderModifier = 10 * getMultipler();
    return _genderModifier.toStringAsFixed(1);}
  }
}
```

**Results Screen**

```
class ResultsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  ResultsScreen({
    @required this.genderMultiplier,
  });

  final String genderMultiplier;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Your Result',
            ),
          ),
          ReuseableCard(
            bgColor: kGreyBackgroundColor,
            cardChild: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  genderMultiplier,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RoundedButton(
            title: 'Re-Calc',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the results screen, how are you doing `Text(buttonTitle)`? It's not referenced in that widget. Based on the code you've written, this should give you an error. Is that your main issue?

Comment: I fixed my code. That was a typo but still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd love to help you if I can but to be honest I'm having trouble understanding what/where your issue is. Can you paste your code in a [flutter pad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter) and share it here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a widget called [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) and it seems you do not really know what it does. And I cannot really help you with the specifics of your code there because I don't know what a `MyButton` is or what `MakeButtons` does. It looks complicated.

But as a matter of fact you don't *need* to know how that widget works, because I don't see any reason why you would use it in your code in the first place.

If in doubt, go with simple. Simple and working is way better than complicated and not working.

Take your calculator class, this is all it really does:

```
String calculate(String buttonTitle) {
  if (buttonTitle == 'Male') return 20.toStringAsFixed(1);

  if (buttonTitle == 'Female') return 10.toStringAsFixed(1); 

  return 'Does not work';
}
```

Try to not over-complicate things.

If you need a three-state selection, why not go with radio buttons? Simple, easy, tutorials all over the internet. That should work. Or use [`ToggleButtons`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html).